# Use Spark structured streaming with StreamingKMeans

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, apache-spark-ml

I want cluster a streaming dataset using Spark. I first tried to use Kmeans but it throws a runtime exception on calling fit method saying it cannot be used with streaming data:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();
```

Then I tried to use StreamingKmeans but it seams this model works only with legacy streaming in Spark and accepts DStream. Does anyone know a workaround for this or other solutions to this problem?

Codes I've written sofar is as follow:

```
        Dataset<Row> df = spark.readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                .option("subscribe", topic)
                .load()
                .selectExpr("CAST(value AS String)")
                .select(functions.from_json(new Column("value"), schema).as("data"))
                .select("data.*");

        VectorAssembler assembler = new VectorAssembler()
                .setInputCols(features)
                .setOutputCol("features");
        df = assembler.transform(df);


        StreamingKMeans kmeans = new StreamingKMeans().setK(3).setDecayFactor(1.0);
        StreamingKMeansModel model = kmeans.predictOn(df);
```

Cannot resolve method 'predictOn(org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset<org.apache.spark.sql.Row>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out it's not possible so I switched to DStream instead of Structured Streaming